# Can anyone identify this white board component in an electronic air filter?

Tags: indicator, neon

[image]
Electronic air filter circuit board component?

Comment: please include all available info ... the components appear to have silkscreened labels

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a very high voltage thick-film resistor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not familiar with this component. As you can see in the photo, the pad for the connection has broken off in the upper left corner of the component. Is it possible to repair as The component is not available from the manufacturer. Can a new pad be soldered to the traces which don’t appear to be metallic but some type printed material. ???

Comment: You cannot solder that. You might try conductive paint or conductive epoxy resin; you'll need something as strong as epoxy to anchor the connecting wire against vibration.

Comment: Thank you Brian. I am going to persue your advice.